# Updating or retraining a deployed project

Tags: microsoft-translator

I have built some Custom translator engines using TM assets. Now I have more content with corrected translations in TMs I would like to use to improve these engines. I am not seeing in the documentation how you can update or retain an engine with new content. What is the process?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a second model in the same project, on the data page. So it's not a retraining, it's a new training.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/custom-translator/quickstart-build-deploy-custom-model

Comment: so everytime we need to retrain (or new train) we again pay for all the existing strings plus the new strings. That makes it very inconvenient and expensive for users!

Comment: If you have new training data, there is no way for us to amend your existing model. We need to train a new one with the new data.